# Getting issue on pdf merge using ghost Script (gs)

Tags: php, ghostscript

Try to merge two pdf files using below command but getting issue. Only blank page come as result.

```
$output = shell_exec('gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=usletter -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=file1.pdf file2.pdf');
```

Comment: You are only specifying one file at the end of the command, beside that I tryed the command and it did work for me (except that usletter is not a valid papersize it should be letter) maybe the issue come from the pdfs. Make sure they are not encrypted.  (I used ghostscipt version 9.25)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes you are right "usletter is not a valid papersize". I have changed and it works on shell but getting issue in PHP file. I think need to enable shell_exec for php file.